# Why does this requestAnimationFrame setup fail to execute properly?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

The function to render my canvas is a prototyped method of a class, like this:

```
Engine.prototype.renderCameras = function() {
        console.log('render ok');
}
```

When I try to run this code directly, it works fine:

```
engine.renderCameras()
>>> render ok
```

When I try to run it using requestAnimationFrame, in either Chrome or Firefox, I get this:

```
window.requestAnimFrame(engine.renderCameras())
>>> render ok
>>> Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS) [nsIDOMWindow.mozRequestAnimationFrame]
```

It runs, but it always throws an error. That's not cool.

When I try to run it like this:

```
window.requestAnimFrame(engine.renderCameras)
>>> 0
```

It just does nothing.

I was able to solve this problem by using a closure, but I'd still like to know why I can't pass a function like that to requestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.requestAnimFrame(engine.renderCameras())
```

is not passing a function to `requestAnimFrame`, it is passing the **return value** of `engine.renderCameras` to `requestAnimFrame`. The return value is probably not a function and that's why you get this error.

```
window.requestAnimFrame(engine.renderCameras)
```

instead correctly passes a function reference, but then [`this` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside `renderCameras` won't refer to `engine`. If you rely on that (which I assume based on the setup), you either have to pass a function calling `engine.renderCameras` properly:

```
window.requestAnimFrame(function(){
    engine.renderCameras();
});
```

or use [`.bind` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set (and bind) `this` explicitly:

```
window.requestAnimFrame(engine.renderCameras.bind(engine));
```

Either way, you have to repeatedly call `window.requestAnimFrame` to get the next animation frame, which means you typically use a recursive function. For example:

```
window.requestAnimFrame(function render(){
    engine.renderCameras();
    window.requestAnimFrame(render);
});
```

Comment: Aah right, I've never actually used .bind() before, but this is the perfect test case.
I actually put my requestAnimationFrame inside a regular setinterval, that way I can set a target fps.